# How do I change the v-progress-loader-circular total time out?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried changing the value to 30 seconds and the resetting the time after 30 seconds but the circle length reminds 100. I want it to count up to 30 and 30 to be the maximum count. I have managed to reset it after 30 seconds but the total count remains the same
[image]

`<v-progress-circular :rotate="-90" :size="100" :width="15" :value="loaderValue" class="mb-2" :color="yellow">`

Answer (score 0):

Change the :value property to a number that you multiply with loaderValue to get 100. For my case. I have used a divider like this

```
this.divider = 100 / this.loaderValue;
<v-progress-circular :rotate="-90" :size="100" :width="15" :value="divider * loaderValue" class="mb-2" :color="yellow">
```